# Best practice for setup and querying versioned records in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to optimize my SQL queries and I always come back to this one issue and I was hoping to get some insight into how I could best optimize this.

For brevity, lets say I have a simple employee table:

**tbl_employees**

```
Id     HiredDateTime
------------------
1      ...        
2      ...
```

That has versioned information in another another table for each employee:

**tbl_emplyees_versioned**

```
Id     Version   Name     HourlyWage
-------------------------------
1      1         Bob      10
1      2         Bob      20
1      3         Bob      30
2      1         Dan      10
2      2         Dan      20
```

And this is how the latest version records are retrieved in a View:

```
Select tbl_employees.Id, employees_LatestVersion.Name, employees_LatestVersion.HourlyWage, employees_LatestVersion.Version
From tbl_employees
Inner Join tbl_employees_versioned
 ON tbl_employees.Id = tbl_employees_versioned.Id
CROSS APPLY 
   (SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS Version
    FROM tbl_employees_versioned AS employees_LatestVersion
    WHERE Id = tbl_employees_versioned.Id
    GROUP BY Id) AS employees_LatestVersion
```

To get a response like this:

```
Id     Version   Name     HourlyWage
-------------------------------
1      3         Bob      30
2      2         Dan      20
```

When pulling a query that has over 500 employees records for which each have a couple few versions, this query starts choking up and takes a few seconds to run.

There are a couple strikes right off the bat, but I'm not sure how to overcome them.

1. Obviously the Cross Apply adds some performance loss. Is there a best practice when dealing with versioned information like this? Is there a better way to get just a record with the highest version?
2. The versioned table doesn't have a clustered index beause neither Id or Version are unique. Concatenated together they would be, but it doesn't work like that. Instead there is a non-clustered index for Id and another one for Version. Is there a better way to index this table to get any performance gain? Would an indexed view really help here?

Comment: Why are the historic versions in the same table as the current version? Can't you just stick them in an archive/audit table?

Comment: If it isn't too late, you might instead have a main table and an archive table. The main table would have the most recent version and the archive table would have all previous (and deleted) versions. I imagine that 99.99% of your query load is for the most recent version.  To support a query that can see the past .01% of the time, versioning like this cranks up the complexity and cranks down the performance.

Comment: Each employee is versioned so that a UI can list the changes of each edit and revert to a specific version is necessary. I figured it's easier to just append versioned records instead of copy records to an archived table before overwriting with a new version. Not the case?

Comment: @Levitikon - Shouldn't be much more effort to have a trigger that archives the previous version of the row at the same time and it saves all your other queries from having to plough through this redundant data. You might also consider having the audit table on a separate file group from the one you are using for current data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to structure the data is using start dates and end dates.  So, the data structure for your original table would look like:

```
create table tbl_EmployeesHistory (
    EmployeeHistoryId int,
    EffDate date not null,
    EndDate date,
    -- Fields that describe the employee during this time
)
```

Then, you can see the current version using a view:

```
create view vw_Employees as
    select *
    from tbl_EmployeesHistory
    where EndDate is NULL
```

In some cases, where future end dates are allowed, the where clause would be:

```
where coalesce(EndDate, getdate()) >= getdate()
```

Alternatively, in this case, you can default EndDate to some future date far, far away such as '01-o1-9999'.  You would add this as the default in the create table statement, make the column not null, and then you can always use the statement:

```
where getdate() between EffDate and EndDate
```

As Martin points out in his comment, the coalesce() might impede the use of an index (it does in SQL Server), whereas this does not have that problem.

This is called a slowly changing dimension.  Ralph Kimball discusses this concept in some length in his books on data warehousing.

Comment: That is amazing brilliant and simple! Thanks Gordan!

Comment: @Levitikon I would still use a separate table though for your use case. The `coalesce(EndDate, getdate())` is unsargable (can't use an index) if future dates are not allowed this might perform OK if `EndDate` is added to the leading column of all indexes or in conjunction with the filtered index feature but still you are bloating your table with two additional columns and extra rows for not much  benefit. (The only benefit I can see is slightly reduced maintenance if the table structure changes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can get a view of the most recent version for each employee:

```
Select Id, Name, HourlyWage, Version
FROM (
  Select E.Id, V.Name, V.HourlyWage, V.Version,
   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY V.ID ORDER BY V.Version DESC) as nRow
  From tbl_employees E
  Inner Join tbl_employees_versioned V ON E.Id = V.Id
) A
WHERE A.nRow = 1
```

I suspect that this will perform better than your previous solution. One index across Id and Version in tbl_employees_versioned would most likely also help.

Also, note that you only need to join on tbl_employees if you're selecting fields that are not in tbl_employees_versioned.

Comment: Thanks Chad, I'm trying to integrate this and see how it goes. Due to brevity I didn't show getting anything from the tbl_emplyees table, but in actually I do.

Comment: This is actually a lot better on performance than what I was using.