# Optimising retrieval of versioned records in SQL using a linked list approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, linked-list

I have an application which has a large table of versioned records – that is to say that a record has a GUID that is shared amongst all its versions (so not a GUID at all), and an integer version number. The GUID and the version number together are the composite key for a specific row.

Business logic dictates that the most common operation when dealing with this table is retrieving the latest version of one or more of these records. The existing code does this in what appears to be the least efficient way possible - for each record, it does a subquery to find the max version number, then selects the record which has that version number.

pseudocode:

```
currentRecord = record where record.ID == "{{guid}}"
    and record.versionNumber == 
        MAX(record.versionNumber where record.ID == "{guid}")
```

I really want to optimise this, but I'm inexperienced with SQL and I'm not sure how. Greater minds than mine have already tried to optimise within the constraints of this design, e.g. there are already all the indexes we can create. And yes, the inefficiency of this operation is a significant issue that's ultimately affecting our users.

The one idea I've had so far, which I intend to experiment with when I have time, is something like a linked list. As well as the version number (which is still needed for display to the user) I thought of adding a *true* GUID `versionID`, and then whenever we create a new version of a record, we point a column `previousVersion` at the previous version, and update the previous version's `nextVersion` column to point at the newly inserted row. This would allow retrieval of latest versions to be simplified to

```
currentRecord = record where record.ID == "{{guid}}"
    and record.NextVersion = NULL
```

Is this a good idea? From my admittedly limited understanding it should improve this operation from O(N^2) to O(N), right? And it doesn't change the cases where we want all the versions of a record in any way. Retrieval is much, much more common than insertion, so the fact that it will take an insert and an update to add a record instead of just an insert shouldn't have any noticeable impact.

Note: There's [a question already from someone with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744221/best-practice-for-setup-and-querying-versioned-records-in-t-sql), as well as a couple of others along the same lines, but nobody suggested this linked list style approach – they did however suggest an approach which ultimately allowed the same null check to find the latest version, however it used start and end dates, which would be confusing in my particular problem space (records already have start and end dates, with a totally different meaning). I suspect that if this was a good idea, someone would have suggested it in an answer to another question, but this idea is bugging me so I'd still appreciate having someone explain why it's terrible.

If it's relevant, I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: You can use `row_number()` to filter to the latest version reasonably efficiently. Or you could simply add a bit flag to the row - `IsLatestVersion`, add it to your index, and keep it up to date.

Comment: Complete DDL of your table, including all of its indices, would definitely help. At least we could cut out the solutions that you already have in place.

Comment: I appreciate it, but for one the general version of this question has been asked multiple times already, so I was thinking I should focus on the differentiating point (the linked list idea), plus I'm not sure I can get away with posting anything that looks too much like production code in this case (I'm new as heck, better safe than sorry)

Comment: You're basically writing metadata to the row at write time. The simplest form of this is what @Blorgbeard suggested - just stamp a 'current row' bit. You can then create indexes filtered in this bit. There's quite a bit of write overhead here though. Could you do it in one big job overnight?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's sort of relevant to the business logic as well though, eg while the most common case is grabbing the latest, we so have to do things like compare a record to the previous one to display changes, etc - so I don't feel like writing this metadata into the row itself is polluting the business data too much. Overnight maintenance would be fine in most cases, but may not be necessary - updates/insertions happen in "human time", nothing programmatic, and only a few thousand users.

Comment: OK so the linked list forms part of the logic - you're not just looking for the latest one. One suggestion for performance improvements is don't use GUID's, use IDENTITY (INT) instead. You can find lots of reasons online why INT are better for keys than GUID's. The only reason for a GUID is if the record must be truly globally unique, i.e. of you have multiple disconnected databases that you want to merge. Certainly the metadata is in no way polluting the record - metadata is a good idea.

Comment: Depending on your SQL Server version you might also want to use temporal tables.

Comment: Ints would be much better, I have a feeling we went for GUIDs because of an admittedly kind of bizarre requirement to segregate the user base into 2 groups (with possibly more to come), each running their own shared version of the application, but allowing for the possibility of combining them all into one in future? I'm not even 100% sure — As you've probably guessed, I'm the new kid on a fairly old and gnarly project.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be fine.  You just need an index on `(id, recordNumber)`.  You would do this in the database:

```
create index t_id_recordNumber on t(id, recordNumber);
```

Your code should automatically use this index.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but do you mean the existing method we have using just a guid and a version number? If so, we already have an index on those columns and it's still very slow.

Comment: @Toadfish, do you have a DBA? Such an index is naturally prone to fragmentation, so you might want to rebuild it once in a while.

Comment: This should maybe be a whole other question instead of a comment, but is there such thing as too many indexes? I'm pretty sure people have been throwing new indexes at every query bottleneck for years... which might answer the question as to whether we have a DBA

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with how this would work/perform, and thought I'd answer my own question to whatever extent I can.

The code for my test can be viewed at http://rextester.com/GKGJX28620, however it's somewhat pointless in this case as this site doesn't display execution plans/statistics. You'll probably have to run it in SSMS or whatever if you're sufficiently curious

I've created two tests so far. In the first, I try retrieving the latest version of a specific record via its record ID (shared amongst all the versions). While in most cases both the old method and the new method resulted in the exact same query (a single index seek) and took the same amount of time to return, other times the old method (with the subquery) would do two index seeks and a stream aggregate instead, and end up being significantly slower.

In the second test I try retrieving multiple records on a non-key column. I observed that the new method was consistently significantly faster. It was always a single index seek, while the old method was always two (plus a stream aggregate). Every time these two queries were run in the same batch, the old method was 71% of total execution time, and the new method 29%.

Overall, this seems to suggest that there's some merit to this idea, but I am in no way qualified to engage in SQL optimisation so I'm happy for someone who *is* qualified to jump in and explain just how badly I screwed up here.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your findings. If the additional processing on insert doesn't affect your insert/update performance then I suggest you forget your doubts and go ahead. Performance issues have a way of a magnifying each other and getting worse over time until they become an emergency. If you address performance issues now in an orderly fashion, that reduces risk in future of having to apply this in an emergency situation.